# How can I determine whether Stored Procedure Parameter is optional from C# code (I am using Sql Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am using C# to connect to Sql Server. I am trying to get Parameter Details of stored procedure before calling the stored procedure. Can you please help me regarding how I can get to know whether any SP parameter is optional or not form C# code itself.

I am using loaclDb in VS 2013. I have Data Source and Db File Name available.

TIA.

Comment: If parameter in initialized in declaration of sp then it's optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like this way:

```
 Server servev = new Server("YourServerName"); 
    Database dataBase = servev .Databases["YourDatabase"]; 
    var paramData = dataBase.StoredProcedures["YourProcedureName"].Parameters;

    foreach(StoredProcedureParameter param in param) {
       string paramName=param.Name;
       string paramValue=param.DefaultValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am using localdb in VS2013. Can you please suggest the answer in that context. I have Data Source and Db File Name with me.

Comment: @Ashutosh_Pandey just do : `Server servev = new Server(); `  to connect your local server. For more information visit this link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms193710.aspx